# Building dav1d with emscripten

Tags: emscripten, meson-build

Can someone please help me setup an emscripten build for dav1d project. I have a bit of experience with `emconfigure ...` and `emmake make ...` builds for other libs, however [dav1d](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d/) compile doc mentions using `meson setup ...` and I am not even sure where to start, and there is nothing like `emmeson` on google.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at one of the repos that has already done it.  It's a bit dated, but this may help:  https://github.com/Kagami/dav1d.js  Unfortunately, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow, but do post any specific question you may have as you get into it.